# Reduce main.js file in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I have an `Angular 16` application which has recently been migrated to standalone components and I was able to remove all modules from the entire codebase. That application has SSR set up for SEO purposes and I normally get a warning from the lighthouse indicating that I should try to reduce unused javascript.

Then I tried to optimize the main.js file which is the biggest JS file I've got and I took a look at the tour of heroes example in the Angular site. I ran `ng build --configuration production` and I got a `main.***.js` file of `320Kb` (then if it is gzipped to the client you get around 100Kb).

Looking at my application I have `348Kb` which isn't too bad compared to the tour of heroes example and only adding 28Kb for a medium-sized application. Is there any way to reduce the size of that file?

Perhaps we can get smaller chunks that may be more efficient but for now I have run the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` and I got the following:

[image]

Which to me seems fairly good. I thought that my `app.component` could be introducing extra dependencies through but that is not the case.

Taking a look at my `main.ts` file I've got:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { bootstrapApplication, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation, withInMemoryScrolling, withRouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import routes from './app/app.routes';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        provideHttpClient(),
        provideAnimations(),
        provideRouter(routes, 
            withInMemoryScrolling({
                scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
                anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
            }),
            withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation(),
            withRouterConfig({
                paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
                onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
            })
        ),
        provideClientHydration()
    ]
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And my `angular.json` for the production build looks like this (very standard):

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/ads.txt",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/",
                "output": "./assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "webpack.config.js"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "aot": true,
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              }
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
```

Note that the `webpack.config.json` is for minimizing the CSS, just that; and the inlineCriticalCss flag is set to false because there is actually better performance server side with it disabled (https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2106)

My `app.component.ts` is very small as well, only importing directly a reference to RouterOutlet, that's it.

I have been looking at many posts and articles and I mostly found the lazy loading approach which I am already doing and I am also delay the reference and load of many elements of the application so that the boostrap can be done the quickest possible way.

Comment: 1) Only load the modules where you actually need them. 2) Organize your modules per feature, so don't use a `SharedModule`!!! 3) Use lazy-loading (=module per page) using the command `ng g module register --module account --route register` 4) For angular libraries, use a separate entrypoint per module/feature ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74012408/using-single-component-from-library-causes-lazy-loaded-modules-to-end-up-in-main))

Comment: Thanks Peter, I migrated to a standalone-model application therefore I don't have any modules, so don't know if many steps are applicable to this. I listed the references I use from Angular in the main.ts file for the dependencies needed and I do lazy load some of the components in the app.component itself (navbar, footer, etc) to reduce the size of the bundle. Not sure of any extra action I can take here

Answer (score 0):

You need to lazy load your modules.

If this is a new project, you'd rather switch immediately to Standalone Components and bootstrap your app with Standalone Apis.

Concerning lazyloaded components, you can do it like that:

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  // Not lazyloaded
  {
    pathMatch: "full",
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { animation: "home" },
  },
  // lazyloaded standalone component
  {
    pathMatch: "full",
    path: "actualite",
    loadComponent: () =>
      import(
        "../components/pages/articles-home-page/articles-home-page.component"
      ).then((m) => m.ArticlesHomePageComponent),
    data: { animation: "articlesHomePage" },
  },
]
```

If you exported your component with export default, you can use the shorter syntax.

```
    loadComponent: () =>
      import(
        "../components/pages/articles-home-page/articles-home-page.component",
```

For routes using same prefix, you can regroup them in a single file exporting routes array too, then use it like this with **loadChildren**:

```
  {
    path: "clients",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./customer.routing").then((m) => m.CUSTOMER_ROUTES),
  },
```

Avoid using commonJS modules like "moment", "slugify"..., as they will induce bigger bundles (not treeshakble)

And that wraps it up.

Comment: Hi millenion, thanks for this. As you can see in the webpack analyzer snapshot everything is lazy loaded since the main.js only contains the Angular stuff as well as the app.component. My question goes more towards how to make the main.js smaller - if possible considering the libraries that are currently referenced as per my screenshot